# In python how do I generate a large amount of cube meshes fast?

Tags: python, 3d

I am trying to generate a large (> 1 million) of cubic meshes that I then will have to reprocess in Blender.

Currently, I do that by actually generating the cubes in Blender using their Python API, like so:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
```

but with a larger number of cubes, it gets increasingly slow.

Are there other approaches I could use? The only requirement is a file format I can later import in Blender, which should not be much of a restriction.

Comment: are you going to add the same mesh?

Comment: Yes, same 1x1x1 cube millions of times, but in different locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`primitive_add_cube` is an operator, which causes a scene update. The more objects you add, the more has be to updated after every addition. So it becomes exponentially slower.

You should avoid that by using the low-level API. If you want to add the same mesh (cube) again and again, simply copy the object. If you don’t be this to be a linked duplicate, also copy the mesh data:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
ob = bpy.context.object

for i in range(-100, 100, 3):
    copy = ob.copy()
    copy.data = ob.data.copy()
    copy.location.x = i

    # use this only for blender < 2.9
    # bpy.context.scene.objects.link(copy)
    
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)


bpy.context.scene.update() # only once

# Moving
ob.location.z = 5
```

Comment: I suspect it's ```bpy.context.view_layer.update()``` i/o ```bpy.context.scene.update()``` but I'm not 100% sure it does the same